# Android Kotlin - set logo inside toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="108dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|end"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnOpenSearch"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                app:tint="@color/colorText"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnProfileImage"
                android:layout_width="42dp"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="6dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/MenuNickname"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_user" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/sign_in"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

The logo isn't showing inside the toolbar, but the icons on the right are

I tried: `toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.logo)` but it not only not works but also makes the icons on the right disappear.

I'm also using `ActionBarDrawerToggle`:

```
toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)

drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    this, drawerLayout, toolbar, 0, 0
)

drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
toggle.syncState()
navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
```

Comment: Did you try to give a background to the imagaview to know if with a flat color it is working? Maybe the problem is with the drawable.

Your actual code looks correct, with the XML should be enough

Comment: @BogdanAndroid I just set a background color for the image and can see it Oo but why not the image itself?

Comment: hummm is the drawable a vector?

Comment: Nope PNG but the image is showing when I set it with Glide for what ever reasons :D You made me try it so you can post this answer and I will check :D

Comment: Nice, one last thing, could you try to put the image using `android:src="@drawable/logo"` I think the problem could be using the compat method. Just for my curiosity hehe

Comment: Yeah it works like that :D I'll do it this way instead of with glide then, thanks!

Comment: Nice to know that! srcCompat was designed for Vectors mostly, maybe was the cause of your problem. I just posted the answer so anyone could see it easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is use the `src` method instead the `srcCompat`:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/logo"
     android:layout_width="108dp"
     android:layout_height="36dp"
     android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```